# Memory limit exceeded bad_alloc

Tags: c++, c++14

I was solving a problem on codeforces and it gave me memory exceeded and even on my local compiler it  says 'std::bad_alloc'
can someone explain why and how to solve this !!!

```
int tst;
cin >> tst;
while(tst--){
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    ll n=s.length();
    string ans;
    if(n==2){
        cout<<s<<endl;
    }
    else{
        if(n%2!=0){
            for(int i=0;i<n;i+2){
                ans.push_back(s[i]);
            }
            ans.push_back(s[n-1]);
        }
        else{
            for(int i=0;i<n;i+2){
                ans.push_back(s[i]);
            }
        }
        cout<<ans<<endl;
    }
    

}
```

Comment: `i+2` -> `i += 2`. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, firstly,  specify your problem statement.

Secondly, please, pay attention to this cycle:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i+2){
    ans.push_back(s[i]);
}
```

The cycle which is written in this way would be infinite, because You are not incrementing `i` at all, and `i` will be equal to zero all way cycle goes(infinite times).

So, additionally, You are trying to enlarge Your container by `n` element in an infinite cycle. You may see, memory is not an infinite resource.

To fix this issue, just rewrite cycle like that:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i+=2){
    ans.push_back(s[i]);
}
```